# Form-data only append last multiple selection

Tags: ajax, jquery-file-upload

This may be duplicate but I can't solve it.
I can send multiple images by JQuery/Ajax to my server (Asp.Net Core) and save them successfully. But the problem is when I want to add the second batch files, the first batch will not append to form data. I add images with a button and not by input type="file" field.

HTML:

```
<form asp-area="User" asp-controller="Item" asp-action="Create" id="createForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input asp-for="ImageUrl" id="myInput" type="file" name="inputFile[]" accept="image/*" multiple style="display:none" />
    <button id="myButton" type="button">+ Add Files</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var inputFile = $('#myInput');
  $('#myButton').click(function () {
     $('#myInput').click();
  });                
  var files = [];
  $('#myInput').change(function () {
     var newFiles = [];
     for (var index = 0; index < inputFile[0].files.length; index++)                                         
       {
          let file = inputFile[0].files[index];
          files.push(file);
       }    
     });
  });            

  $("#createForm").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('createForm'));
      //var formData = new FormData(this);
      files.forEach(file => {
          formData.append('file[]', file);
      });
      for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
          console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
      }

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          url: $("#createForm").attr('action'),
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          data: new FormData(this),
      });
  });  

});
```

Suppose I choose pictures 1,2,3 and submit my form and all 3 pictures save to server side successfully. Now let's try a new record: I add pictures 1,2,3, after that I choose pictures 4,5,6 so I expect to 6 images to be appended to form data. But only the last selection 4,5,6 are saved to server !

This is my console report in below.As you  can see I have `input-File[]=3` !! Something like I have no jquery and no ajax and just using pure `HTML/Input Multiple file` and I can upload only my last selections !!

[image]

But when I refresh my page and choose just 1,2,3 images (one selection only), I have `input-File[]=3` and `file[], [object File]=3` and every thing is good.

I tried `data: new FormData()` and `data: formData` and many other options on data parameter but no one could solve my problem :(

Update : ******************************:

```
Case 1: 
 var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('createForm'));
 .   .   .
 data: formData,
```

Results: No image save in server and ImageUrl is null in database.

```
 Case 2:
 var formData = new FormData()
 .   .   .  
 data: formData,
```

Results in error in console : `XML Parsing Error: no root element found`

```
 Case 3:
 var formData = new FormData(this)
 .   .   .
 data: formData,
```

`Results` : suppose I select images 1,2,3 at first and then select images 4,5,6. I have images 1,2,3,4,5,6 saved on server and 4,5,6 save twice !! I'm getting near but still can't manage it.

.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an error in the way that you copied your code. There is an extra `});` after `$('#myInput').change(function () { ... });`
I'm assuming that is not part of the issue and was just a mistake in pasting it over.

The issue I think is that you were trying to send the files over separately from the inputFiles. Updating the for loop in the submit event handler should give you what you are wanting.

```
$("#createForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach((file) => {
        formData.append('inputFile[]', file);
    });

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: $("#createForm").attr('action'),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: formData,
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed to `formData.append('inputFile[]', file)` nothing changed and still the last selection is sent to server but the console log changed, now I have two line : `inputFile[], [object File]   6`   and `inputFile[], [object File]   3`. But still 1,2,3 images are  uploaded. Another point changing to  `data: formData` and `var formData = new FormData();` resulted in error `XML Parsing Error: no root element found` . Please read the Update.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the issue. If you select images 1,2,3 and submit they should be uploaded. Then if you select images 4,5,6... are you wanting 1,2,3 to upload again or are you only wanting 4,5,6? At first I was under the impression that you wanted all 6. But after your update I'm not so sure. "Results : suppose I select images 1,2,3 at first and then select images 4,5,6. I have images 1,2,3 and again 1,2,3,4,5,6 saved on server !! I'm getting near but still can't manage it." Makes it seem like you don't want 1,2, 3.

Comment: I found some more info on the error you are getting. I was testing in chrome and did not get the error. I think it is firefox only - https://ovinitech.blogspot.com/2019/01/xml-parsing-error-no-root-element-found.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. May be my poor English ... . Any way, I need all 6 images together ... but I want the user to be able to add them from different folders so user may not select them at once but need them all to be uploaded. But I have images selected at last, twice. Update edited.

Comment: I think the 4,5,6 going twice is because you are saving them in ```file[]``` when the input changes. I was having the same issue while I was testing. That is why I switched it to```var formData = new FormData()```. Did you try in Chrome or Edge to see if you still get the ```XML Parsing Error```?

Comment: – Jordan : your trigger moved me to answer. Thank you. I added `$("#myInput").val("");`  to my submit button, so I remove last input files which saved in input-file element, and only my appended images saves to server with no duplication.